# Клик по метке яндекс карты(api 2.1), добавление класса блоку лежащему в данной метке

Tags: javascript, jquery, яндекс-карты

Яндекс карта api 2.1. Вместо стандартной метки, ставится верстка. Нужно по нажатию на метку, добавлять класс в верстку которая находится в данной метке, а у остальных удалять класс. Event у метки я понял как добавить

```
place.events.add('click', function (e) {});
```

А как теперь взять класс блока который внутри этой метки, и добавить к ниму еще один???

```js
var myMap, ymaps;
// Инициализировать карту
function init_point_map() {
  var winWidth = $(window).width();
  myMap = document.getElementById("map");
  if (!myMap) return;
  myMap = new ymaps.Map(myMap, {
    center: [55.753215, 37.622504],
    zoom: 11,
    controls: []
  });

  myMap.controls.add("zoomControl", {});
  if (winWidth <= 1024) {
    myMap.behaviors.disable('drag');
  }

  var data = {
    'points': [{
        "infoPoint": '<div class="point">\
    <div class="point__temp-wrp">\
     <div class="point__temp"><span class="status-weather" style="background-image: url(images/overcast-day.svg);"></span> 19.6 С <sup>o</sup></div>\
     <div class="point__temp_road">\
      <svg class="icon icon-highway"><use xlink:href="#icon-highway"></use></svg>\
      10.6 С <sup>o</sup>\
     </div>\
     <div class="point-photo"><svg class="icon icon-photo-camera"><use xlink:href="#icon-photo-camera"></use></svg></div>\
    </div>\
   </div>',
        "latitude": 55.737789,
        "longitude": 37.524173,
      },
      {
        "infoPoint": '<div class="point">\
    <div class="point__temp-wrp point__temp-wrp_red">\
     <div class="point__temp"><span class="status-weather" style="background-image: url(images/overcast-day.svg);"></span> 19.6 С <sup>o</sup></div>\
     <div class="point__temp_road">\
      <svg class="icon icon-highway"><use xlink:href="#icon-highway"></use></svg>\
      10.6 С <sup>o</sup>\
     </div>\
     <div class="point-photo"><svg class="icon icon-photo-camera"><use xlink:href="#icon-photo-camera"></use></svg></div>\
    </div>\
   </div>',
        "latitude": 55.703489,
        "longitude": 37.605884,
      }
    ],
  };

  var results = [];
  data.points.forEach(function(item, index) {
    results.push(createPlacemark(item));
  });
}


// Создать метку
function createPlacemark(item) {
  var options = Object();
  var squareLayout = ymaps.templateLayoutFactory.createClass(item.infoPoint);
  var place = new ymaps.Placemark(
    [item.latitude, item.longitude], {
      hintContent: false
    }, {
      iconLayout: squareLayout,
      iconShape: {
        type: 'Rectangle',
        coordinates: [
          [-12, -20],
          [192, 12]
        ]
      }
    }
  );
  place.events.add('click', function(e) {
  
  });
  myMap.geoObjects.add(place);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  if (ymaps != undefined) ymaps.ready(init_point_map);
});
```

```css
#map {
  width: 600px;
  height: 450px;
}

.point {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 123;
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  top: -6px;
  left: -6px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #12ac0f;
}

.point_active {
  transform: scale(1.5);
}

.point__temp-wrp {
  position: absolute;
  min-width: 150px;
  height: 20px;
  left: 24px;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -10px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 12px;
  background-color: #97d830;
  line-height: 12px;
}

.status-weather {
  background-color: #76ab22;
}

.point__temp-wrp_red {
  background-color: #b2152f;
}

.point__temp-wrp_red .point__temp:before {
  border-right-color: #901328;
}

.point__temp-wrp_red .status-weather {
  background-color: #901328;
}

.point__temp {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-right: 7px;
  height: 20px;
}

.point__temp:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  right: 100%;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -10px;
  border-right: 10px solid #76ab22;
  border-top: 10px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 10px solid transparent;
}

.point__temp .status-weather {
  width: 25px;
  background-size: 15px;
}

.point__temp_road {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 12px;
  height: 20px;
}

.point__temp_road .icon {
  width: 10px;
  height: 12px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -6px;
}

.point-photo {
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  float: left;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.point-photo .icon {
  width: 12px;
  height: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -5px;
  margin-left: -6px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?lang=ru_RU"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Сам решил проблему)))

```js
     var myMap,ymaps;
   // Инициализировать карту
   function init() {
    var winWidth = $(window).width();
    myMap = document.getElementById("map");
    if (!myMap) return;
    myMap = new ymaps.Map(myMap, {
     center: [55.753215, 37.622504],
     zoom: 11, 
     controls: []
    });

    myMap.controls.add("zoomControl", {});
    //myMap.behaviors.disable('scrollZoom');
    if(winWidth <= 1024){
     myMap.behaviors.disable('drag');
    }
    

  var data = {
    'points': [{
        "infoPoint": '<div class="point{% if properties.active %} point_active{% endif %}">\
    <div class="point__temp-wrp">\
     <div class="point__temp"><span class="status-weather" style="background-image: url(images/overcast-day.svg);"></span> 19.6 С <sup>o</sup></div>\
     <div class="point__temp_road">\
      <svg class="icon icon-highway"><use xlink:href="#icon-highway"></use></svg>\
      10.6 С <sup>o</sup>\
     </div>\
     <div class="point-photo"><svg class="icon icon-photo-camera"><use xlink:href="#icon-photo-camera"></use></svg></div>\
    </div>\
   </div>',
        "latitude": 55.737789,
        "longitude": 37.524173,
      },
      {
        "infoPoint": '<div class="point{% if properties.active %} point_active{% endif %}">\
    <div class="point__temp-wrp point__temp-wrp_red">\
     <div class="point__temp"><span class="status-weather" style="background-image: url(images/overcast-day.svg);"></span> 19.6 С <sup>o</sup></div>\
     <div class="point__temp_road">\
      <svg class="icon icon-highway"><use xlink:href="#icon-highway"></use></svg>\
      10.6 С <sup>o</sup>\
     </div>\
     <div class="point-photo"><svg class="icon icon-photo-camera"><use xlink:href="#icon-photo-camera"></use></svg></div>\
    </div>\
   </div>',
        "latitude": 55.703489,
        "longitude": 37.605884,
      }
    ],
  };

    var myCollection = new ymaps.GeoObjectCollection();

    var results = [];
    data.points.forEach(function(item, index){
      results.push(createPlacemark(item));
    });
    myMap.geoObjects.add(myCollection);

   // Создать метку
    function createPlacemark(item) {
     var options = Object();
     var squareLayout = ymaps.templateLayoutFactory.createClass(item.infoPoint);
     var place = new ymaps.Placemark(
      [item.latitude, item.longitude],
      {
       hintContent: false
      }, 
      {
          iconLayout: squareLayout,
          iconShape: {   
              type: 'Rectangle',
              coordinates: [
                [-12, -20], [192, 12]
              ]
          }
        }
     );
     myCollection.add(place);
    }
    var thatCoordinates;
    myCollection.events.add('click', function (e) {
     //myCollection.get('target').properties.set('active', false);
     var that = e.get('target').properties.get('active');
     myCollection.each(function(item, index){
      item.properties.set('active', false);
      if(e.get('target') == item && !that){
       e.get('target').properties.set('active', true);
       thatCoordinates = e.get('coords');
      }
     });
    });
   }

   $(document).ready(function(){
    if (ymaps != undefined) ymaps.ready(init);
   });
```

```css
#map {
 position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.point {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 123;
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  top: -6px;
  left: -6px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #12ac0f;
}

.point_active {
  transform: scale(1.5);
}

.point__temp-wrp {
  position: absolute;
  min-width: 150px;
  height: 20px;
  left: 24px;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -10px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 12px;
  background-color: #97d830;
  line-height: 12px;
}

.status-weather {
  background-color: #76ab22;
}

.point__temp-wrp_red {
  background-color: #b2152f;
}

.point__temp-wrp_red .point__temp:before {
  border-right-color: #901328;
}

.point__temp-wrp_red .status-weather {
  background-color: #901328;
}

.point__temp {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-right: 7px;
  height: 20px;
}

.point__temp:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  right: 100%;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -10px;
  border-right: 10px solid #76ab22;
  border-top: 10px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 10px solid transparent;
}

.point__temp .status-weather {
  width: 25px;
  background-size: 15px;
}

.point__temp_road {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 12px;
  height: 20px;
}

.point__temp_road .icon {
  width: 10px;
  height: 12px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -6px;
}

.point-photo {
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  float: left;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.point-photo .icon {
  width: 12px;
  height: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -5px;
  margin-left: -6px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?lang=ru_RU"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
```